# How to solve these 3 statements about vectors?

Tags: geometry, vectors, solution-verification

Let **a** and **b** be vectors in $\ R^3 $

Which of the following statements are true:

Statement 1 : $$ (a × b) − (b × a) = 0 $$

Statement 2 : $$ (a + b) · (a × b) = 0 $$

Statement 3 : $$ |a × b|^2 + (a · b)^2 = |a|^2 |b|^2 $$

I've written my solutions below, could you please check them and help me with statement 3?

So for Statement 1 I did the following:

$\ (a × b) − (b × a) = 0 $

$\ (a × b) ≠ (b × a) $

Thus, the first statement is false.

For Statement 2:

$\ (a + b) · (a × b) = 0 $

$\ (a + b) · (a × b) = 0 $

I considered **(a+b)** as **c** and applied the following property: $\ a · (b × c) = (a × b) · c $ $\ (1)$

So I get:

$\ ((a + b) × a) · b = 0 $

I applied the following property $\ a × c + b × c $ $\ (2)$ by taking **(a + b)** as **c**

So:

$\ (a × a + b × a) · b = 0 $  Knowing that a × a is 0

$\ (b × a) · b = 0  $

Then I applied the property in $\ (1)$ to obtain the following:

$\ (a × a + b × a) · b = 0  $ and $\ (a × a) = 0 $ so:

$\ (b × b) · a = 0  $

To get a · 0 = 0, 0=0

So this statement is true.

Did I do any illegal move in these two proofs? And how can I solve the 3rd Statement?

Comment: $a\times b=|a||b|\sin\theta$ and $a\cdot b=|a||b|\cos\theta$. Further $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally when proving something you want to write out a full sentence explaining things. Let's look at the first one. Here you wrote $a \times b \neq b \times a$, which is true. It is useful to provide an example in a proof. Let's try finding one. We have $e_1 = (1,0,0), e_2 = (0,1,0), e_3 = (0,0,1)$. Notice $e_1 \times e_2 = e_3$, but $e_2 \times e_1 = -e_3$. Thus $e_1 \times e_2 - e_2 \times e_1 = e_3 - (-e_3) = 2e_3 \neq 0,$ so it cannot be true in general.

For the second, notice that $a \cdot (a \times b) = 0$ and $b \cdot (a \times b)  =0$. The reason why is that $a \times b$ gives a vector orthogonal to both $a$ and $b$, and $a \cdot b = |a| |b| \cos(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$. Now by the distributive property, we have $(a+b) \cdot (a \times b) = a \cdot (a \times b) + b \cdot (a \times b) = 0.$
I could not really follow the argument you laid out.

For the last property recall that
$$ a \cdot b = |a| |b| \cos(\theta), \qquad a \times b = |a| |b| \sin(\theta),$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors. Thus

$$ |a \cdot b|^2 + |a \times b|^2 = |a|^2|b|^2 (\cos(\theta)^2 + \sin(\theta)^2) = |a|^2 |b|^2$$
using the Pythagorean identity.

Comment: So my solution for statement 2 is correct but it could've been simplified by just understanding the first sentence that you gave, isnt it?

Thank you very much, I understand the 3rd statement as well. Appreciate it.

Comment: The first sentence is why statement 2 is correct, the second sentence is explaining why the first statement is correct and then the third sentence explains how you use the first sentence to prove statement 2. Let me know if anything is confusing.